# How to underline label with underline effect in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I followed [this](http://smstuebe.de/2016/08/29/underlinedlabel.xamarin.forms/) tutorial to create underline effect. However, when my page starts it breaks without exception being caught. Has anyone managed to create underline effect? Here is a code:

UnderlineEffect.cs:

```cs
namespace XX.CustomForms
{
    public class UnderlineEffect : RoutingEffect
    {
        public const string EffectNamespace = "XX.CustomForms";

        public UnderlineEffect() : base($"{EffectNamespace}.{nameof(UnderlineEffect)}")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

UnderlineLabel_Droid.cs:

```cs
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName(UnderlineEffect.EffectNamespace)]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(UnderlineEffect), nameof(UnderlineEffect))]
namespace XX.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class UnderlineEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            SetUnderline(true);
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            SetUnderline(false);
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(args);

            if (args.PropertyName == Label.TextProperty.PropertyName || args.PropertyName == Label.FormattedTextProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                SetUnderline(true);
            }
        }

        private void SetUnderline(bool underlined)
        {
            try
            {
                var textView = (TextView)Control;
                if (underlined)
                {
                    textView.PaintFlags |= PaintFlags.UnderlineText;
                }
                else
                {
                    textView.PaintFlags &= ~PaintFlags.UnderlineText;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot underline Label. Error: ", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my xaml:

```
    xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:XX.CustomForms;assembly=XX"

    <Label Text="Privacy Notice" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" >
        <Label.Effects>
            <custom:UnderlineEffect />
        </Label.Effects>
    </Label>
```

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far?

Comment: And especially, what is the exception that you get?

Comment: I added code. I don't get exception. Application breaks on call to InitializeComponent(); and exception can not be caught with try/catch. There is just message on phone "Unfortunately, XX has stopped."

Comment: Check your build output carefully, I think there is some kind of exception info in there. Only thing I could think of in the code you posted is in the `OnElementPropertyChanged` method that some property is null while initialising and breaks.

Comment: I tried to put breakpoints everywhere but it doesn't stop on them. Debugger goes to InitializeComponent(); and breaks immediately.

Comment: Are you running a debug build? And what does the exception say there? Also again, check the output window in Visual Studio, especially for Android this window can contain hidden information on crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to add an underline to a label, we created custom renderers that inherits from Label.

```cs
public class CustomLabel : Label
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsUnderlinedProperty = BindableProperty.Create("IsUnderlined", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomLabel), false);

    public bool IsUnderlined
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(IsUnderlinedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsUnderlinedProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

In your xaml page you can use it as:

```xml
<s:CustomLabel IsUnderlined="True" Text="UnderlinedText" FontSize="18" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
```

Note that `s` is the namespace declared in the root element of xaml page.

Now your renderer in Android would be something like that:

```cs
public class CustomLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null && Element != null)
        {
            if (((CustomLabel)Element).IsUnderlined)
            {
                Control.PaintFlags = PaintFlags.UnderlineText;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but does custom renderer cost more resource than effect ? and will it eventually affect the app's performance ?

Comment: @LêGiaLễ This was 2 years ago and I haven't worked with Xamarin since then. However, if you still want to achieve this, it looks like Xamarin added the effect directly without the need to create a custom renderer. Look at [hvaughan3's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53973999/6783663)

Answer (score 45):

Xamarin Forms added a `TextDecorations` property to `Label`s. Update to Xamarin Forms 3.3.0+ and just set:

C#

```
Label label = new Label {
    TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline
}
```

XAML

```
<Label TextDecorations="Underline"/>
```

[Docs Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.label.textdecorations?view=xamarin-forms#applies-to)

Be aware that there was a bug on iOS when an underlined `Label` is in a `ListView`. Looks like it has been fixed and released in 3.5.0. I am still using a custom renderer on iOS for now until I am ready to update to the latest version.

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4295)

So continue using the iOS effect if you have not updated to XF 3.5.0 yet.

Answer (score 14):

The lengths some people are going to to get underlined text in Xamarin is insane. Here's a way to do it without a thousand line custom renderer. The negative margin trick came from [this guy](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/238068/#Comment_238068).

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Start">
    <Label Text="Underlined Text" />
    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Purple" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,-7,0,0" />
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use TextDecorations property in Label class.

`<Label Text="Underlined Text" TextDecorations="Underline"/>`